# spring-boot-maven-plugin doesn't create fat jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to package my REST service. I'm building the jar using `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package`. After I decompile the jar, I don't find any of the dependencies added (I was expecting it to be a fat jar with all dependencies)

[image]

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <phase>install</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
              <goal>build-info</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
        <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run the spring boot using `java -jar myapp.jar -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=qal"` I'm getting ClassNotFoundException for many of the classes. It's clear that artifact didn't build as expected. However, if I start spring boot application using maven `./mvnw spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=qal"` I guess, it finds all the dependencies in target folder hence works fine. How can I fix the build issue so that I can start app using java -jar command.

EDIT: It's multi-module maven project

Comment: Judging by the screenshot, there are a number of problems with the repackaged jar. Where’s the screenshot from? Also, what do command line tools like `jar` and `unzip` show for the jar’s contents?

Comment: I used JD-GUI (http://jd.benow.ca/) for unzipping the jar and screenshot is after unzipping using jd-gui

Comment: What do command line tools like jar and unzip show for the jar’s contents?

Comment: Jars are just zip files with manifest so you can use unzip to see the contents. 

    i.e. 

    unzip -l <jar-file> will show the contents.

    You can also peruse the contents if you know the path from the list.

    i.e. This will print the manifest:

    unzip -p target/scila-adapter-service.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it seems you are using a wrong command. `mvn clean package` is maven command, you should use command 'repackage', it used for

> Repackages existing JAR and WAR archives so that they can be executed
>   from the command line using java -jar

as it mentioned here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html

Or probably it's plugin configuration issue. Just checked: it works with `spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.0.RELEASE`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                 <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I used "mvn clean  package spring-boot:repackage". I see all project classes are compiled and added to the jar but dependencies are still missing and I continue to get the ClassNotFound error for dependencies

Comment: Found the reason why it wasn't working. My project is multi module maven project. Need to use classifier as per this documentation. It works with 1.5.9.RELEASE version as well. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html

Comment: The link posted in the answer is broken

Comment: Fixed link: [repackage-classifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html)

Answer (score -2):

Use this one

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
    <executable>true</executable>
    <fork>true</fork>
    <!-- Enable the line below to have remote debugging of your application on port 5005
         <jvmArguments>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>
     -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, please give a short description on why or how this code will solve the OPs question.

Comment: The answer does not explain what and how the original issue will get solved.